# Is Monero mining profitable with 600 H/s?

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, gpu-mining, hashrate, mining-profitability

I checked the hash speed of my system. It is around 600 H/s for an intel i7 processor.

I checked this with crypto compare profit calculator:

Hash power: 600 H/s,
Power consumption: 50w,
Electricity cost: $0.1/KWh,
Pool fees: 1%

It is showing me a loss of $0.12 everyday resulting in a monthly loss of $2.12

What is the actual reality of Monero mining at a hash rate of 600 H/s? I am sure people will not mine for a loss.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I want to ask that if I purchased Nvidia GTX 750 gpu what will be my daily, weekly and n monthly income.guide me with details please.

Comment: https://2cryptocalc.com/ this website might help you spot profitable GPU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hash power: 600 H/s, Power consumption: 50w, Electricity cost: $0.1/KWh, Pool fees: 1%

> What is the actual reality of Monero mining at a hash rate of 600 H/s?

Clearly you will make a loss unless the price of XMR grows significantly against the dollar.

> I am sure people will not mine for a loss.

Correct. Anyone remotely serious about mining will buy hardware that mines significantly faster than 600 H/s and will locate their hardware where they can secure cheap electricity - the combination of which to make it actually profitable.